# Use php to set a mysql session variable @

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

**I have a Moodle site and i would like to create a mysql trigger using the id of the logged user.**

Is it possible to use php to set a custom mysql session  variable ( User-Defined Variable).

My goal is to get the id of the logged user and put il in a mysql global variable in order to use that information in a mysql trigger.

Something like:   `SET @utilisateur = $USER->id;`

I was thinking of adding a line of that kind at the end of the file index.php to catch the id of the logged user but i don't know the exact syntax

`$query .= "SET @utilisateur = $USER->id;";`  doesn't work

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: user defined variables are sessiojn bond and not global can you elaborate what you trying to do

Comment: In short i want to be able to write a trigger in mysql to prevent a user of deleting a line (BEFORE DELETE) if his id doesn't match the one on the line.  Since i can't get the user that is logged with mysql, i want to pass it to mysql using php.

Comment: databases have rows not lines. only for your information

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want but if `$USER->id;` has the id you want then in quotes you need `"SET @utilisateur = {$USER->id}"` or `"SET @utilisateur = ".$USER->id`

Comment: I try both but none of them work  Thanks for your time

Comment: THis will need to be done prior to _each query_. It cannot be done "per session" as it seems you're wanting. Might be best to have  a delete wrapper function that appends "and user_id={$USER->id}" to all `where` statements

Comment: Ok i understand..